# after navigate to another page, bootstrap dropdown become unusable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I had 3 .php files, they are index.php, load_file.php,and register.php

1. In index.php, contain navigation, and each navigation has dropdown list, i call this navigation and the dropdown from database. and also index.php has link to register.php, note : load_file.php included in this file
2. In load_file.php, contain code to check value of page, by using if($_GET['page']),and trigger every value with switch-case
3. register.php, just a normal form

> My problem is, after I navigate to register.php by typing ?page=register in browser, my dropdown in index.php file become unusable

**::UPDATE::**

this is my **index.php** file

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once './model/functions.php';

    if(isset($_GET["category"])){
        $index_page= $_GET["category"];
        $index_sub_page= null;
    }elseif (isset ($_GET["sub_category"])) {   
        $index_sub_page = $_GET["sub_category"];
        $index_page= null;
    }else{
        $index_sub_page= null;
        $index_page= null;
    }
    
    if($_POST){      
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        
        if(check_username_and_password_from_users($username, $password)){
            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>Learn Bootstrap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>
            <div id="TopContainer" class="container">
                <div class="pull-right navbar-default">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <?php if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){ ?>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?></a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 17px;">
                                <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <?php }else{ ?>
                      <!--dropdown here -->
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="login">Dropdown</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding:17px;">
                                <form id="loginform" method="post" action="index.php" class="form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="?page=register">Register</a></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="logo" class="container">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a class="navbar no-margin" href="#"><img src="picture/LogoSaya.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                            </span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <nav class="container">
                <div class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <?php
                            $subject_set =  find_all_subjects();
                            while($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set)){
                        ?>
                        
                        <li>
                            <a id="dLabel" data-target="#" href="?subject=<?php echo urlencode($subject["id"]);?>" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" role="button">
                                <?php echo $subject["name"];?>
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                          <!--dropdown here -->
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                                <?php
                                    $page_set = find_pages_from_subjects($subject["id"]);
                                    while($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_set)){
                                ?>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="?category=<?php echo urlencode($page["id"]);?>"><?php echo $page["name"];?></a>                                        
                                        <ul>
                                            <?php
                                                $sub_page_set = find_sub_pages_from_pages($page["id"]);
                                                while($sub_page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sub_page_set)){
                                            ?>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="?sub_category=<?php echo urlencode($sub_page["id"]);?>"><?php echo $sub_page["name"];?></a>
                                            </li>
                                            <?php
                                                }
                                                clear_result($sub_page_set);
                                            ?>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>                  
                                <?php
                                    }
                                    clear_result($page_set);
                                ?>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        
                        <?php
                            }
                            clear_result($subject_set);
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="container">
                <?php
                    include "load_files.php"; //this is to load the files
                ?> 
            </div>
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

to navigate register.html, i use this code

```
<li><a href="?page=register">Register</a></li>
```

as you can see, i put code on below in index.php

```
           <?php
                include "load_files.php"; //this is to load file
            ?>
```

and this is my **load_files.php**

```html
<?php
    if($_GET){
        switch ($_GET['page']) {   
            case 'register':
                if(!file_exists("register.html")){
                    die("Sorry Empty Page");
                }
                include 'register.html';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an event handler issue. I'd look at how you are adding event handlers and see if the handler is getting wiped out somehow.

Answer (score 0):

**::SOLVED::**

> My problem is, after I navigate to register.php by typing ?page=register in browser, my dropdown in index.php file become unusable

this problem happen because, i had 2

```html
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

, inside index.php and register.html .by remove the one inside register.html will solve the problem